# Code works with jquery toggle but not toggleClass

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have looked all over the web, done the toggleClass tutorials and have seen them work. However, in my own efforts to upgrade a working toggle method listed below I am struggling. The toggleClass method opens once but does not style the css markup and does not toggle closed. The toggle method works fine. I cannot understand why the css markup is not picked up in toggleClass, which I have commented out below for comparison, so some helpful boffin can guide me. I really need some help. – Tx. Gordon Eddey.

```
            <head>



            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("summary.detailsSUMMARY").click(function(e){

                             var toggleDETAILS = $(this).next("section.detailsSECTION");
                                  toggleDETAILS.toggle();
                                                                })
                                    .css("cursor", "pointer");
                                    });
            </script>

            <!--
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("summary.detailsSUMMARY").click(function(e){
                                 var toggleDETAILS = $(this).next("section.detailsSECTION");
                                  toggleDETAILS.toggleClass("detailsSECTION");
                                                               })
                                    .css("cursor", "pointer");


                                     });

            </script>
            -->


            <style>
            .detailsSECTION{
                display:none;
                font-size:200%;
                color:red;
            }
            </style>

         </head>

         <body>



            <details id="DETAILSdetails">


        <details class="detailsDETAILS">
                                <summary class="detailsSUMMARY">
                                 <h2 class="detailsH2">DISCLOSE 0000</h2> 
                                 </summary>

         <section class="detailsSECTION">


                                    <nav class="detailsNAV">
                                                <ol class="detailsOL">
                            <li><a href="#d0001" target="_self">Details article 0001</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0002" target="_self">Details article 0002</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0003" target="_self">Details article 0003</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0004" target="_self">Details article 0004</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0005" target="_self">Details article 0005</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0006" target="_self">Details article 0006</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0007" target="_self">Details article 0007</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0008" target="_self">Details article 0008</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0009" target="_self">Details article 0009</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0010" target="_self">Details article 0010</a></li>
                                                </ol>
                                                </nav class>
             </section>
                            </details>

                </section>
                </details>


            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: i mean... surely you could understand why `$(this).next("section.detailsSECTION")` would no longer select the section if the section no longer had said class. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) is working as it should work. In your code you have applied class detailsSECTION to the section which you want to toggle & also applied some styles to same class.
so when you use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method it removes the class from that section which removes the styles which you had applied when it runs first time. Later when you click again you are using following code `var toggleDETAILS = $(this).next("section.detailsSECTION");` which will read next elements having the class detailsSECTION but its not there as it was removed when you clicked the first time hence it dose not toggle back.

I suggest you use another class like .hide having just the display:none style and then toggle this class in your code.

your code will look something like this after changing. But, if you are using it for just hiding and showing your current code is better.

```
<head>



            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("summary.detailsSUMMARY").click(function(e){

                             var toggleDETAILS = $(this).next("section.detailsSECTION");
                                  toggleDETAILS.toggle();
                                                                })
                                    .css("cursor", "pointer");
                                    });
            </script>

             -->
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("summary.detailsSUMMARY").click(function(e){
                                 var toggleDETAILS = $(this).next("section.detailsSECTION");
                                  toggleDETAILS.toggleClass("hide");
                                                               })
                                    .css("cursor", "pointer");


                                     });

            </script>



            <style>
            .hide{
             display:none;
            }
            .detailsSECTION{

                font-size:200%;
                color:red;
            }
            </style>

         </head>

         <body>



            <details id="DETAILSdetails">


        <details class="detailsDETAILS">
                                <summary class="detailsSUMMARY">
                                 <h2 class="detailsH2">DISCLOSE 0000</h2> 
                                 </summary>

         <section class="detailsSECTION hide">


                                    <nav class="detailsNAV">
                                                <ol class="detailsOL">
                            <li><a href="#d0001" target="_self">Details article 0001</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0002" target="_self">Details article 0002</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0003" target="_self">Details article 0003</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0004" target="_self">Details article 0004</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0005" target="_self">Details article 0005</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0006" target="_self">Details article 0006</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0007" target="_self">Details article 0007</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0008" target="_self">Details article 0008</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0009" target="_self">Details article 0009</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d0010" target="_self">Details article 0010</a></li>
                                                </ol>
                                                </nav class>
             </section>
                            </details>

                </section>
                </details>


            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shreyas, particularly for taking the time to answer the question in some depth. I now see that the problem in the original code was 'display:none', which admittedly did not appear in any of the tutorial examples I tried.

Comment: Ah Shreyas, I stupidly pushed the button the wrong way and it automatically listed -1 before I could change it. Sorry. I in fact think your answer is worth maximum points to me. As you can tell, I am a bit of a noob at this even though I have been a member – largely inactive – for quite some time. I have clicked plus one a few times. I hope that changes the score.